# Why cant i update my html model after choosing yes to play again?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to update my db to show a new score but it keeps coming back as null. I know the element is created and when I check it keeps saying it is null. I have used console log to see that i am hitting the function but cant debug further?

createDB.sql

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS THUNTDB;

CREATE DATABASE THUNTDB;

use THUNTDB;

CREATE TABLE USER (
    USER_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    USER_EMAIL varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    USER_PASS varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    USER_LOW int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
);
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">        

    <style>
        #loginBtn, #logoutBtn, #registerBtn, #resetLowBtn
        {
            display: none;
        }

        a, a:hover
        {
            color: white;    
        }
        .box
        {
          height: 50px;  
          background-color: black;
          border: white 2px solid;
        }

        .prize
        {
            background-color: green !important;
        }

        .flipped
        {
            background-color: red !important;
        }

        .selected
        {
            color: blue;
        }            
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mb-0">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4">THUNT</h1>
            <p class="lead">The coolest thunt on the web!</p>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-start border p-2 bg-dark text-light">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" id='resetLowBtn' class='nav-link'>Reset Low Score</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" id='loginBtn' class='nav-link'>Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" id='registerBtn' class='nav-link'>Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" id='logoutBtn' class='nav-link'>Logout</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <span id="msg"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>            
    <div class="container">
        <!--boxes-->
        <div id='game'>
            <div id='boxes' class='row'>
            </div>

            <p>Guesses: <span id='guesses'>0</span>  Low Score: <span id='lowScore'>N/A</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>        

    <!--put your modal dialogs here...-->
    <div id='confirm' class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-light">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Play Again?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Would you like to play again?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id='yes' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>           
    <div id='loginDlg' class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-light">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Login</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Login</h4>
                    <form class="border border-primary p-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id='confirmLoginBtn' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div id='registerDlg' class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-dark text-light">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Register</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Register</h4>
                    <form class="border border-primary p-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="regEmail" name="regEmail" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="regPassword" name="regPassword" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id='confirmRegisterBtn' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {
        // model ....
        let model = {};
        let Gmodel= {};

        function initializeModel()
        {
            sendRequest("whoIsLoggedIn", function(){});
            let boxCount = 10;
            Gmodel.guesses = 0;
            Gmodel.boxes = [];
            let prize = Math.floor(Math.random() * boxCount);
            for (var i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) 
            {
              Gmodel.boxes.push({flipped: false, prize: false});
            }
            Gmodel.boxes[prize].prize = true;
            Gmodel.gameOver = false;                
        }

        // view...
        function updateView()
        {
            console.log(model);
            console.log(Gmodel);
            if (model.result == undefined)
            {
                $("#msg").text(model.error);
                $("#logoutBtn").hide();
                $("#loginBtn").show();
                $("#registerBtn").show();
                $("#resetLowBtn").hide();
                $("#game").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#logoutBtn").show();
                $("#resetLowBtn").show();
                $("#loginBtn").hide();
                $("#registerBtn").hide();
                $("#msg").text("Hello " + model.result.email);
                $("#game").show();
                $("#boxes").empty();                
                for (var i in Gmodel.boxes) 
                {
                    let item = $("<div class='col-6 box'></div>");
                    if (Gmodel.boxes[i].flipped && Gmodel.boxes[i].prize)
                    {
                      item.addClass("prize");
                    }
                    else if (Gmodel.boxes[i].flipped && !Gmodel.boxes[i].prize)
                    {
                      item.addClass("flipped");
                    }
                    item.attr("id", i);
                    $("#boxes").append(item);
                }

                $("#guesses").text(Gmodel.guesses);                    
                $("#lowScore").text(model.result.low);                    
            }
        }            

        // controller ...
        function sendRequest(url, callback)
        {
            var jqxhr = $.get(url);
            jqxhr.done(function(json) 
            {
                model = json;
                updateView();
                if (callback !== undefined)
                    callback();
            })
            jqxhr.fail(function(json) 
            {
                let error = JSON.stringify(json);
                model.error = error;
                updateView();
            })
        }

        $(document).on("click",".box",function() 
        {
            if (Gmodel.gameOver == true)
            {
              return;
            }

            let i = $(this).attr("id");
            if (!Gmodel.boxes[i].flipped)
            {
              Gmodel.guesses = Gmodel.guesses+1;
              Gmodel.boxes[i].flipped = true;
              if(Gmodel.boxes[i].prize)
              {
                Gmodel.gameOver = true;
                $('#confirm').modal('show');
              }
              else
              {
                updateView();
              }
            }
        });

        $('#yes').click(function() 
        {
            $('#confirm').modal('hide');
            sendRequest("updateLow?low=" + Gmodel.guesses, function(){});
            sendRequest("whoIsLoggedIn", function(){});
            initializeModel();
            updateView();


        });            

        $('#loginBtn').click(function() 
        {
            $('#password').val('');
            $('#loginDlg').modal('show');
        });

        $('#registerBtn').click(function() 
        {
            $('#regEmail').val('');
            $('#regPassword').val('');
            $('#registerDlg').modal('show');
        });

        $('#logoutBtn').click(function() 
        {
            sendRequest("logout", function() 
            {
                $("#boxes").empty();
                initializeModel();
                updateView();
            });

        });

        $('#confirmLoginBtn').click(function() 
        {
            let email = $('#email').val().trim();
            let password = $('#password').val().trim();

            sendRequest("login?email="+email+"&password="+password, function ()
            {
                // if (model.error == undefined)
                //     sendRequest("listSongs");    
            });
            $('#loginDlg').modal('hide');
        });

        $('#confirmRegisterBtn').click(function() 
        {
            let email = $('#regEmail').val().trim();
            let password = $('#regPassword').val().trim();
            sendRequest("register?email="+email+"&password="+password, function () 
            { 
                // if (model.error == undefined)
                //     sendRequest("listSongs");
            });

            $('#registerDlg').modal('hide');
        });

        // run...
        initializeModel();
        updateView();
    });


    </script>
</body>
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// added so we can serve index.html...
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var mysql = require('mysql');

// install first using npm install bcrypt
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const conInfo = 
{
    host: process.env.IP,
    user: process.env.C9_USER,
    password: "",
    database: "THUNTDB"
};

var session = require('express-session'); 
app.use(session({ secret: 'happy jungle', 
                  resave: false, 
                  saveUninitialized: false, 
                  cookie: { maxAge: 600000 }}))

app.all('/', serveIndex);                  
app.all('/whoIsLoggedIn', whoIsLoggedIn);                  
app.all('/register', register);
app.all('/login', login);
app.all('/logout', logout);
app.all('/updateLow', updateLow);



app.listen(process.env.PORT,  process.env.IP, startHandler())

function startHandler()
{
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + process.env.PORT)
}


function updateLow(req, res)
{
  var con = mysql.createConnection(conInfo);

  console.log("@updateLow");
  let sql = `UPDATE USER
           SET USER_LOW = ?
           WHERE USER_ID = ?`;

  let data = [req.query.low, req.session.user.result.id];

  // execute the UPDATE statement
  if(req.query.low  <  req.session.user.result.low || isNaN(req.session.user.result.low)){
      con.query(sql, data, (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error){
        return console.error(error.message);
      }
      console.log('Rows affected:', results.affectedRows);
    });
  }
}

function whoIsLoggedIn(req, res)
{
  if (req.session.user == undefined)
    writeResult(req, res, {'error' : 'Nobody is logged in.'});
  else
    writeResult(req, res, req.session.user);
}

function register(req, res)
{
  if (req.query.email == undefined || !validateEmail(req.query.email))
  {
    writeResult(req, res, {'error' : "Please specify a valid email"});
    return;
  }

  if (req.query.password == undefined || !validatePassword(req.query.password))
  {
    writeResult(req, res, {'error' : "Password must have a minimum of eight characters, at least one letter and one number"});
    return;
  }

  var con = mysql.createConnection(conInfo);
  con.connect(function(err) 
  {
    if (err) 
      writeResult(req, res, {'error' : err});
    else
    {
      // bcrypt uses random salt is effective for fighting
      // rainbow tables, and the cost factor slows down the
      // algorithm which neutralizes brute force attacks ...
      let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.query.password, 12);
      con.query("INSERT INTO USER (USER_EMAIL, USER_PASS, USER_LOW) VALUES (?, ?,?)", [req.query.email, hash,10], function (err, result, fields) 
      {
        if (err) 
        {
          if (err.code == "ER_DUP_ENTRY")
            err = "User account already exists.";
          writeResult(req, res, {'error' : err});
        }
        else
        {
          con.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_EMAIL = ?", [req.query.email], function (err, result, fields) 
          {
            if (err) 
              writeResult(req, res, {'error' : err});
            else
            {
              req.session.user = {'result' : {'id': result[0].USER_ID, 'email': result[0].USER_EMAIL, 'low': result[0].USER_LOW}};
              writeResult(req, res, req.session.user);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });

}

function login(req, res)
{
  if (req.query.email == undefined)
  {
    writeResult(req, res, {'error' : "Email is required"});
    return;
  }

  if (req.query.password == undefined)
  {
    writeResult(req, res, {'error' : "Password is required"});
    return;
  }

  var con = mysql.createConnection(conInfo);
  con.connect(function(err) 
  {
    if (err) 
      writeResult(req, res, {'error' : err});
    else
    {
      con.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_EMAIL = ?", [req.query.email], function (err, result, fields) 
      {
        if (err) 
          writeResult(req, res, {'error' : err});
        else
        {
          if(result.length == 1 && bcrypt.compareSync(req.query.password, result[0].USER_PASS))
          {
            req.session.user = {'result' : {'id': result[0].USER_ID, 'email': result[0].USER_EMAIL, 'low': result[0].USER_LOW}};
            writeResult(req, res, req.session.user);
          }
          else 
          {
            writeResult(req, res, {'error': "Invalid email/password"});
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

function logout(req, res)
{
  req.session.user = undefined;
  writeResult(req, res, {'error' : 'Nobody is logged in.'});
}

function writeResult(req, res, obj)
{
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
  res.end('');
}

function validateEmail(email) 
{
  if (email == undefined)
  {
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
  }
}

function validatePassword(pass)
{
  if (pass == undefined)
  {
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    var re = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/;
    return re.test(pass);
  }
}

function serveIndex(req, res)
{
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
  res.end(index);
}
```

***there is  a script tag missing in the code I copied, above the jquery, after the divs. Its giving the text box issues, or rather I am.

What I am trying to figure out is why i cant seem to update the Low score after choosing to play again. If I logout it will be updated when I log back in but not after just choosing to play again.

Comment: Can you please separate your files out into separate code blocks and let us know whether update on the client side you mean you are trying to connect to the DB from the client side or not?

Comment: To me, your server.js looks like express, but you did not specify and do not provide enougbh context for us to actually know

Comment: I uploaded more of my code. In mostly the proper way. I've made some progress but am still not getting the results i want

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add another SQL statement to reconnect to the updated user.

```
function updateLow(req, res)
{
  var con = mysql.createConnection(conInfo);

  console.log("@updateLow");
  let sql = `UPDATE USER
           SET USER_LOW = ?
           WHERE USER_ID = ?`;

  let data = [req.query.low, req.session.user.result.id];



  if(req.query.low  <  req.session.user.result.low || isNaN(req.session.user.result.low)){
      con.query(sql, data, (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error){
        return console.error(error.message);
      }
      else
      {
        con.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_EMAIL = ?", [req.session.user.result.email], function (err, result, fields) 
        {
          if (err) 
            writeResult(req, res, {'error' : err});
          else
          {
            req.session.user = {'result' : {'id': result[0].USER_ID, 'email': result[0].USER_EMAIL, 'low': result[0].USER_LOW}};
            writeResult(req, res, req.session.user);
          }
        });
      }
      console.log('Rows affected:', results.affectedRows);
    });
  }
}
```